# Load multiple css simultaneously using functions.php

Tags: theme-development, css

There's the default style.css and the one from prismjs.

Current scenario: 
Default CSS loads first, then the javascript for prism kicks in and the code tags are styles. The delay is a fraction of a second, but it's still noticeable.

What I'm trying to achieve:
Highlighted code and pre tags upon the first load.

My enqueue code

```
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );

function add_prism() {

wp_register_style(
'prismCSS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path-to/prism.css'  );
wp_register_script(
'prismJS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path-to/prism.js'    );
wp_enqueue_style('prismCSS');
wp_enqueue_script('prismJS');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_prism');
```

I tried calling the default stylesheet after prismcss, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_prism');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Comment: i dont get it, is prismCSS or prismJS dependent of the default CSS? what do you mean by `Highlighted code and pre tags upon the first load.` if you are talking about files...

Comment: I have defined default css properties for pre and code tags in my style.css.  Highlighting the code is done by prism. Basically, first the style.css properties and loaded and then prism properties override the style.css ones.

Comment: have you tried with loading the script `async`?

Comment: I tried this method: [Async with WordPress Enqueue](https://ikreativ.com/async-with-wordpress-enqueue/)
This didn't have any effect though

Comment: Have you tried adding a dependencies array like `wp_register_style(
'prismCSS', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path-to/prism.css', array('theme-style')  );` to load prism after theme-style?

Comment: @czerspalace but that's what's been happening now. I 'm trying to load prism along with style.css, or before it so that there's no one-second delay before syntax highlighting is done to my pre and code tags.